# Mail not delivered in sql

Tags: sql, database, email

I am using sql server 2008 and is using database mail for sending emails.
when i am using sp_send_dbmail procedure the mail is not getting sent to the recipient.
While checking the log, the sent_status is showing failed.
Please help me to send mail.

Comment: You should provide more information. Start with the code you are currently using and errors given. Include anything you have already attempted.

Comment: Did you input the creds in order for it to send like the smtp, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this to setup your email in SQL 2008:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/